# Adding leading zeros to a file name using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have about 1500 files that have the name <number>.jpg. For example, *45312.jpg*, *342209.jpg*, *7123.jpg*, *9898923.jpg*, or 12345678.jpg

The total number before the extension should be 8 digits. So I need to add leading zeros for if it less than 8 digit to make an 8-digits file name.

```
00001234.jpg
00012345.jpg
00123456.jpg
01234567.jpg
```

I tried this PowerShell script, but it's complaining.

I tried this, but the output is the same

```
$fn = "92454.jpg"
"{0:00000000.jpg}" -f $fn
```

OR

```
$fn = "12345.jpg"
$fn.ToString("00000000.jpg")
```

Comment: “{0:d4}” -f $fn does not do the job either. out put is same as the file name.

Comment: Her's a solution in C#: https://dotnetfiddle.net/S4vscU

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You had it right, but the {0:d8} only works on numbers, not strings, so you need to cast it correctly.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Path\To\Files | Where{$_.basename -match "^\d+$"} | ForEach{$NewName = "{0:d8}$($_.extension)" -f [int]$_.basename;rename-item $_.fullname $newname}
```

Answer (score 11):

```r
'92454.jpg' | % PadLeft 12 '0'
```

Or

```r
'92454.jpg'.PadLeft(12, '0')
```

Result

```
00092454.jpg
```

[PadLeft Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/92h5dc07)