# Add leading zero to file names using PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, leading-zero

I have a folder that contains multiple hunderd .mp3-files, all with the same name and an ascending number. The filenames look like this:

```
Test 01.mp3
Test 02.mp3
Test 03.mp3
Test 100.mp3
Test 101.mp3
Test 102.mp3
```

As you can see, the number of leading zeros in the first files is wrong, as they should have one more. I'd like to use PowerShell to solve the problem as I am currently learning to operate this quite helpful tool.

I tried to count the digits in the file names using the Replace Operator to filter out any non-digit characters. I assumed that the first 99 files would have three digits while the other files would have more (counting the '3' of the .mp3 file extension)

`Get-Childitem | Where {($_.Name.Replace("\D","")).Length -le 3}`

That should give me any files that have  3 or less digits in their file name - but it doesnt. In fact, it shows none. If i increase the number at he end to 11, i get the first three test files, increasing it to 12 shows all six of them. I assume that the Replace-Operator doesn't get applied to the file name before the filtering based on the Length-Operator, although I used brackets around $_.Name.Replace("\D","")

What the hell am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I figures it out: `Get-ChildItem | Where {($_.Name -replace "\D","").Length -le 3}` returns the files that I need to rename.
The whole command I used was

`Get-ChildItem | Where {($_.Name -replace "\D","").Length -le 3} | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "Test ","Test 0"}`

Its also possible to rename all files to an number-only scheamtic and use the padleft command as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877248/adding-leading-zeros-to-a-file-name-using-powershell)

Comment: just for added detail, the `-f` string format operator can do it, too. it has a numeric format option that will let you stuff the number into as many digits as you want.

Answer (score 1):

By replacing `"Test "` with `"Test 0"`, you would still not achieve what you want on files that are numbered `Test 1.mp3` (as this will become `Test 01.mp3`, which is one leading zero short).

You can make sure all files will have a 3-digit sequence number by doing this:

```
Get-Childitem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter '*.mp3' -File | 
    Where-Object {$_.BaseName -match '(\D+)(\d+)$'} | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { '{0}{1:D3}{2}' -f $Matches[1], [int]$Matches[2], $_.Extension }
```

With this, also wrongly named files like `Test 00000003.mp3` wil be renamed as `Test 003.mp3`

Answer (score 0):

If you know how long the number should be represented, you can use [`ToString`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-leading-zeroes-when-displaying-a-value-in-windows-powershell/) to transform an `int` into an *n* digits-long `string` (with potential leading 0s). For instance to have a 3 digits-long number you can use `.ToString('000')`.

So for the question:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { $_.BaseName -match '\d+' | Out-Null; $digits = $Matches[0]; Rename-Item $_ ($_.Name -replace $digits, ([int]$digits).ToString('000')) }
```

(The `Out-Null` is to prevent the `-match` output to be displayed.)